# Abaqus slows down considerably when generating a large number of wire elements, what could I be doing wrong?

Tags: python, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

For a project I need to generate a large number (70000 + ) wires. I wrote a python script for it, but after a while abaqus almost completely stops. It generates about 4000 wires in 30 min, 16000 wires in 9 hrs, and 17000 wires in 15 hrs.
I use the following to generate the wires inside a simple while loop.

```
mdb.models['Model-1'].rootAssembly.WirePolyLine(mergeWire=OFF, meshable=OFF, points = ...))
```

I tried splitting up the while loop to segments (because the initial 4000 wires were generating so quickly) but it didn't help. When there are a large number of wires in the model it slows down inevitably.

As far as I know I can't make Abaqus change the number of cores it uses while *generating* the model. I would appreciate any and all opinions on this.

Comment: you might be better off to create an inp file mesh and import it as an orphan mesh.

Comment: This, I think, will only happen when you have an active CAE session. If you run the script from the command line using the `nogui` option then it should complete much more quickly.

Comment: @MattP I could try doing that, but is there a way of saving the model as .cae from command line? I need it because I need pictures of the complete model as well as run it with various different BC's.

Comment: @agentp I am sorry I am new to both python and abaqus so both of those things are alien to me. Would you mind explaining what an inp file and an orphan mesh are and how I could go about creating an inp file?

Comment: you can just do `mdb.save()` to save.  `inp` is the abaqus input file (if you have ever submitted a job you will have one to look at).  It is a fairly simple matter to create you own directly defining nodes and elements.